# cfldap get 1st value from an attribute separated by comma

Tags: coldfusion, ldap

I want to be able to assign a session variable from a ldap query of an attribute, but the attribute has commas separating the data, all i want is the first value from the attribute

```
<cfldap action="query"
                name="auth"
                attributes="uid, cn, mail"
                referral="yes"
                start="#LDAP_root#"
                scope="SUBTREE"
                server="#LDAP_server#"
                port="#LDAP_port#"
                filter="#userfilter#"
                username="#LDAP_username#"
                password="#LDAP_password#"
                secure = "CFSSL_BASIC"
                separator = ","

            > 
<!--- auth cn can have multiple values separated by a comma, i just want the first --->
<cfset session.fullname = auth.cn>
```

I am guessing a loop or a list, but unsure

Comment: If you have a list you can do `listFirst(variable,delimiter)` if the list is comma delimited you can ignore the delimiter.

Comment: @MattBusche make this an answer and i'll accept, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list you can do `listFirst(variable,delimiter)` if the list is comma delimited you can ignore the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use either the **listGetAt()** or **getToken()** functions, and specify which element you want, as well as the delimiter. Which may be handy if you want say the second or third element.

```
<cfset foo = listGetAt(list, position, delimiter) />
```